# how to clear and add source data dynamically in jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

this is my jquery code.year is form input tag id.years is array variable it's contain all years values.i put this array in autocomplete source.it's working fine.but once i set autocomplete source equal null after set autocomplete source years array did not work.how to solve this problem?

```
$("#year").blur(function() {
    var keyEvent = $.Event("keydown");
    keyEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
    $(this).trigger(keyEvent);
    // Stop event propagation if needed
    return false;
}).autocomplete({
    autoFocus : true,
    source : years,
    selectFirst : true,
    select : function(event, ui) {
        variableyear = (ui.item.lable);
    }
});
```

code for clear source data:

```
$("#year").autocomplete('option', 'source', null);
```

Comment: It's really hurt my eyes for reading your question. Could you give a little effort to correct your format (upper cases, indent...)?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting an empty array as the source:

```
$("#year").autocomplete({source: []});
```

or

```
$("#year").autocomplete('option', 'source', []);
```

Comment: Did you try both of them?